# Get all record without attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

Given a model with ActiveStorage

```rb
class Report
  has_one :report_file
end

class ReportFile
  belongs_to :report
  has_one_attached :file
end
```

How can I get all Report where file in ReportFile not attached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `left_joins` method in Rails 5, so you can use this instead of `includes` (or `eager_load`, which works here in the same way), since it fits better in this case. Also, the table you really should join to get what you want is `active_storage_attachment`, which is associated as `file_attachment` to `ReportFile`. Thus, I think the best way to get what you want is:

```
Report.left_joins(report_file: :file_attachment).where(active_storage_attachments: { id: nil })
```

Answer (score 1):

Attachment associations have the following naming convention: _attachment. In your case, this would be file_attachment.

Since this is a regular ActiveRecord association, you can do joins with it. The query you're looking for, then, is:

```
Record.where(id: RecordFile.where.not(id: RecordFile.joins(:file_attachment)).pluck(:record_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Report.joins("left join report_files on reports.id = report_files.report_id").where("report_files.file is null")
```

will work

Answer (score -1):

```
Report.eager_load(:report_file).where(report_file: {file: nil})
```

should work

Comment: `report_files` table name in the query

Comment: It's not gonna work, there's no such column as `file` in `report_files` table.

Comment: agree. idea is more towards using "includes" , we can change where condition to based on column generated by activestorage

Answer (score -1):

Report.includes(:report_files).where('report_files.file= ?',nil)

Ref:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes